# Chef Inspec Test JSON output from an HTTP API

Tags: json, ruby, http, chef-infra, inspec

I am trying to create a inspec control where i need to check the status in a json file which gets downloaded when hitting a http url.
When i hit http://localhost:5000/aaa/bbb/ccc/v1/healthCheck url a file gets downloaded(healthCheck.json).
I am trying to execute the below code

```
control "file_check" do
  http_request = http('http://localhost:5000/aaa/bbb/ccc/v1/healthCheck')
  describe json(content: http_request.body) do
    its('status') { should eq 'success' }
  end
end
```

The error i am getting is

```
"results": [
            {
              "status": "failed",
              "code_desc": "Control Source Code Error a00972-http/controls/http.rb:5 ",
              "run_time": 0.0006573,
              "start_time": "2019-06-13T09:56:57+10:00",
              "message": "undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass",
              "exception": "RuntimeError",
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [json resource](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/json/), you are not accessing the json path correctly.

change:

```rb
its('status') { should eq 'success' }
```

to:

```rb
its(['results', 0, 'status']) { should eq 'success' }
```

please note that the value of `results[0].success` is `failed`